# MongoDB Aggregation use value from Match Object in pipelin

Tags: mongodb

i'm using the following aggregation:

```
    const aggregate = [
  {
    $match: {
      mainCatId: new ObjectId(catId),
    },
  },
  {
    
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "products",

      "pipeline": [
        { "$match": { "subCategory": '$_id' } },
      ],
      "as": "products"
    }
  },
  { "$unwind": "$products" }

];
```

The problem is that i have to match the id of each doc in the pipeline section but this is not working. So the question is how can i match the id i"m getting from the match above

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Is the syntax below, which uses [the traditional syntax for single join conditions](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/#equality-match-with-a-single-join-condition), what you are looking for?

```
const aggregate = [
  {
    $match: {
      mainCatId: new ObjectId(catId),
      
    },
    
  },
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "products",
      localField: "subCategory",
      foreignField: "_id",
      "as": "products"
    }
  },
  {
    "$unwind": "$products"
  }
]
```

If not, please provide sample documents and further details about the ways in which your current approach (and this proposed solution) are not working.